# Partial section cuts with Google Sketchup

Tags: sketchup

Is there any way of creating a section in Google Sketchup which cuts away one layer, but not another?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make group the objects, then go into it(edit group), and make a Cut /Section Plane.

if it a component, do the same way but the other same components will affected too...you can make unique component to isolate it.